# ReferenceError after using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix

This is the content of `app.js`:

```
function hi()
{
  alert('Hi');
}
```

After bundling it with webpack*, I get a large file [app-min.js](https://pastebin.com/D5ykeuKz).

If I create now a plain html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="/js/app-min.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

            hi();
        });      
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: hi is not defined
```

I double-checked that the path `/js/app-min.js` exists. So why can't I access the function? Or, how can I access it?

---

.* I actually used laravel-mix on top of webpack. Thats how I used it:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app-min.js')
```

Comment: I just answered more or less exactly the same question a couple days ago, see above.

Comment: @AKX yes just 6 days ago. Not sure how I missed it, sorry. I try to get it working with laravel-mix, then I will mark it as duplicate, if it is straightforward.

Comment: @AFK okay, `window.hi = hi` is the key.